# set up sane network scanner daemon on windows

Tags: java

I have successfully setup scanner daemon on ubuntu and used jfreesane to scan documents from a HP network scanner.I am trying to setup sane scanner daemon on windows since last 2 weeks.My question is,

1.Is it possible to use scanner daemon on ubuntu over internet and use scanner in my local network make use of this daemon on internet?

2.Otherwise,Could you explain how can i setup sane daemon on windows? I have installed mingw on windows and downloaded source code for sane backends but couldnt compile it due to error I am getting follwoing error.

abaton.c:62:22: fatal error: sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success with the Cygwin environment rather than with Mingw.

Someone managed to build Saned with Mingw, but it was in 2009 for only one scanner, and I am not sure patches (if any) moved back to the upstream project.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I could set up cygwin and compiled scanner source code successfully.I have a network hp scanner with local ip.192.168.1.X I am able to ping it from cygwin command
Now I am getting "scanimage: no SANE devices found"